# Are empty strings allowed as enum members in Java

Tags: java, ingres

I'm having a bit of a problem with some legacy code.  A ticket asks for me to write a script testing the validity of a process; however, I keep getting this exception when the script is run:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class edu.cmu.s3.common.enums.RegistrationStatus.;
```

For the record, the database being used is an old Ingres legacy system, so null values are being represented as empty strings -- quite beautiful, I have to add.

Anyway, it looks like whenever an empty string is encountered, it fails on enum creation.  I checked the enum, though, and it contains this member:

```
BLANK("", "Blank")
```

This would make me think that an empty string is indeed a valid argument, but it looks like it's not.

CAN enums use empty strings as arguments, or will I need to update more legacy code than I initially assumed?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you think that `NULL equals empty string` is beautiful?

Comment: The problem will be in the code itself, may the stacktrace be with you. :)

Comment: I figured it was a case of obvious facetiousness. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An empty string is a valid *argument for an enum constructor* - but it's not a valid enum *name*.

Every enum value name has to be a valid Java identifier.

Comment: You're right.  I'm using iBatis to populate data objects, and the exception referred to a mapping between the offending attribute and enum.  I changed the query to return 'BLANK' if the value was '', else return what was given, and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `Enum.valueOf(String)` to parse `Strings` from your database into `Enums`, then your problem is that `valueOf` keys off of the `Enum` name itself, i.e. `BLANK`.

This would work for you: `Enum.valueOf( "BLANK" )`

But not: `Enum.valueOf( "" )`

If you wanted to parse `Enums` based on some other field pased into the `Enum` constructor, you would have to write that code yourself.