# How to set empty string as Java enum value?

Tags: java, enums

I am facing a problem when handling with empty java string as java enum value. Its throwing IllegalArgumentException when reading the "" data.

```
updateType = records.get(11);
UpdateMethodType updateMethod = null;
String empty = "";
if (updateType != null || !updateType.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Update type ----->" + updateType);
    updateMethod = KalturaUpdateMethodType.valueOf(updateType);
} else {
    updateMethod = KalturaUpdateMethodType.valueOf(empty);
}
```

Please help me resolving this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are empty strings allowed as enum members in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179785/are-empty-strings-allowed-as-enum-members-in-java)

Comment: From the generated documentation of the `valueOf` method of any enum: “The string must match exactly an identifier used to declare an enum constant in this type.” and “Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if this enum type has no constant with the specified name.” Examples are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-), [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-), and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 2):

There can't be any empty enum value. you can instead have a special enum value named EMPTY in `KalturaUpdateMethodType`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behavior. You should not pass empty string to `valueOf()` method. and if you pass null you will get a NPE. 
So better you create a new enum for EMPTY string.
Like :

```
enum KalturaUpdateMethodType {
    EMPTY("");
    String value;
    private KalturaUpdateMethodType(String value) {
      this.value = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: & Sidgate - Thanks a lot. Its a client class which we cannot modify. So we set that value to one of enum value. The problem was while retrieving it was retrieving as empty string. So I thought I can handle this. But came to know this. Thanks for answering me.